# Designing an object that is treated as if it was of type int even though it is not

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I have a class `C` that represents an integer the value of which is not known. `C` implements all methods that allow it to be used in arithmetic expressions (including `__add__`, `__sub__` and so on), generally returning a new object of type `C`.

I would like to trick the python interpreter into believing that an object of type `C` is indeed an integer even though it is not. So, for instance, I would like to be able to write something like:

```
c = C()
for i in range(c):
  print(i)
```

Currently, doing so produces the error: `TypeError: 'C' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Instead, I would like the range function to think that `c` is an integer and to try executing its code treating `c` as a valid integer (possibly resulting in an error later on when `c` is used in an operation the `C` type does not support or for any other reason).

In general, I do not want `c` to evaluate to a specific integer, I just want it to say to anybody who asks for its type (as the range function apparently does) "Hey! I am an integer, believe me!".

I don't know whether this can be accomplished subclassing `int` in a smart way but all my recent attempts have failed.

I have also tried to overload the method `__index__` of the class `C` which is used to convert objects of type `C` to integers, but I am not allowed to return `self` from within that method since `self` is not of type `int`.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

**Use Case**

I am trying to achieve this functionality to implement a dynamic symbolic executor for Python code. Given a function `f` that takes in input an integer number, using my library it is possible to call the function `f` on an object `s` of type `SymbolicInt` (which is of the abovementioned type `C`). The object `s` is used by the function code. Whenever it is used in an operation like `s` + 3, the result is a symbolic expression of the form `SymbolicAdd(s, 3)`. Ideally, all operations involving symbolic integers return symbolic expressions rather than concrete values. When the boolean value of a symbolic expression that is known to evaluate to a boolean type (like `SymbolicLessThan(SymbolicInt('x'), 10)`) is requested, my library evaluates whether it exists any value for the variable `x` to make the condition hold `True` and whether it exists any value for the variable `x` to make the condition hold `False`. In the case both values for `x` exist, the current Python process is forked and the two independent processes keep executing the code, one assuming that the expression is `True` and the other that it is `False`.

Effectively, this means that all possible execution paths of the function that takes in input the symbolic input are explored, rather than only one as it normally happens when a concrete input is executed.

Back to the `range` related example, range takes in input an integer (actually at most 3 integer, but let's consider the simple case) and does operations on such integer (as setting a counter to 0, performing a while loop until such counter is different from the provided integer, incrementing the counter by 1 at each step (I know it is not exactly like this but let's assume it is for the sake of clarity)). Now, when the symbolic integer in input to range is used in a boolean expression, my library takes care of forking the current process (if necessary) and returning concrete boolean values for it but until then it is just a symbolic integer with no predefined values that can transform itself into symbolic expressions while it is used in various operations.

The problem I have now is that range refuses to accept a `SymbolicInt` object as input on the basis that "it is not an int", but I would like it to accept it anyway and use it in operations and branching conditions as if it were.

I hope this clarifies my intent.

Comment: You need to return an integer from `__index__`. What integer value should `c` have, exactly - how many times should that `print` get called? How can we possibly tell you that?

Comment: The problem is exactly that `c` has no predefined integer value assigned to it when it is passed to the range function. When `c` is used in a boolean expression such as `c < 3`, an integer value for `c` is produced on the fly so that it evaluates to `True` or `False` but until `c` is used like that it has no value. 

I need `c` to be taken as input by the range function "as is", without assigning any concrete value to it. I don't care if the range function returns an error at runtime using `c` later on. My goal is to make the function think that `c` is an integer.

Comment: Your requirements make no sense to me. Could you give some more context around what you're actually trying to achieve, beyond *"make the function think that `c` is an integer"* - why? What should the output of `for i in range(c): print(i)` be?

Comment: @AndreaAquino: you *are* getting an error at runtime; you can't create a `range()` without concrete boundary values. A `range()` is a sequence, it has a length and it 'contains' a sequence of integers you can index into or iterate over. You can't create a range without knowing the concrete boundaries of that range.

Comment: Sounds like you need to define your own range object that produces some determined behaviour when it has unknown bounds. eg. `iter(CRange(C()))` might produce an infinite iterator and each time the iterator produces a value it increases the lower bound of the `C` object.

Comment: Surprising enough, when you create a class that inherits from `int`, and when you give it an attribute that has an integer value, you can use it as an `int` object, **even though** you did not implement __add__ or such methods.

Comment: I clarified my intent editing the question.

@MartijnPieters: I don't know whether what you are saying is true. The range function returns an iterator which can mostly be accessed as a sequence but stores no explicit sequence in memory (only the start and end point of the sequence and the "step" parameter). I am perfectly able to create a class that behaves as a symbolic range in which the end points are symbolic (i.e., have no concrete values) but I would like to use the existing implementation of the range function without forcing users to modify their code to use my library.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into `sympy`, which already does symbolic math - if nothing else, you could crib their ideas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you, I am aware of sympy, maybe I will find a way to do what I need there :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you thought this through. `range()` doesn't just take that `int` input, it bases it's whole behaviour around the numeric value of that integer. Passing in an 'unknown' integer makes no sense there, because without a *concrete numeric value* for that object, how is `range()` supposed to know the boundaries of the range when iterated over?

In other words, `__index__` is used whenever a concrete integer value is expected. Anything that *wants* to use `__index__` doesn't want an `int`, it wants a concrete number.

If your type cannot provide a concrete value, then it should not implement `__index__` and it *can't be used in those contexts*.

For your specific use-case, it sounds as if you would have to *fork for every possible int value* of your symbolic integer. If you already set an upper bound `3` on that value, that means you need to for your processes into 4, with concrete `int` values of `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. The `range()` then produces a sequence yielding between 0 and 3 concrete integers.

I must urge you to also look into [static type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) and reason about the code without running it. Projects like [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) can already infer a lot of information from code using static parsing alone, and tools like [Facebook Infer](http://fbinfer.com/) can go further still and pick out possible states for the code being analysed (although not for Python code).

Comment: Thank you Martijn, it looks like there is no easy way around my problem. I appreciated the link to mypy and Facebook Infer even though their goal is completely different from mine and I cannot achieve my goal without running the code. I think you got my point about the expected behavior of the range function in this case. Truth be told I have a solution for this specific use case already which is based on a local-scope replacement of the range function with a custom implementation that works with symbolic expressions but I find it rather hacky and I am looking for alternatives.